# ListViewItem Trigger messed up the ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, triggers

I have already tried googling this problem, but just couldn't find a solution.
So my problem is that when putting the trigger into the code, it just messes it up, or to be more exact, the data I inputted by binding it, doesn't show up. The whole part between ListView.Resources is the problem, since I tried it whithout that part, and the data worked fine.

Just to clear some things up: Yes the code does work(just the data doesn't show up) and the trigger does too(when mouse is over it turns red).

```
<ListView Name="benutzerListe" ItemsSource="{Binding BDatens}" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="5" Background="White" Height="450" Width="800" Margin="90 180 90 0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectionMode="Extended" >
                    <ListView.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                                        <Border x:Name="Bd" 
                                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                            Background="Transparent" 
                                            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                                <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" 
                                                    Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                                                    ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" 
                                                    HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" 
                                                    VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                        </Border>
                                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="Red"/>
                                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="#A826A0DA"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </ListView.Resources>
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Id" Width="145">
                                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" FontSize="15"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Vorname" Width="210">
                                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Vorname}" FontSize="15"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Nachname" Width="210">
                                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Nachname}" FontSize="15"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Passwort" Width="220" >
                                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Passwort}" FontSize="15"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn>
                            <GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
                                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
                                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="17"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkRed"/>
                                </Style>
                            </GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
```

**The Window should show the ListView with the Items and their data(Id's, surname's, name's, password's) but only "ePharmacy.BDaten" shows up.**

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? So that I can see the data + trigger?

Comment: The ControlTemplate in the ListViewItem Style uses a ContentPresenter element, although you want different GridViewColumns to be shown, and hence use a GridViewRowPresenter. Why are you declaring this ControlTemplate at all?

Comment: If I'm fully honest, there are a few things that I still have to learn regarding XAML and WPF. But I thought I could use the ControlTemplate for triggering something?
What should I do then?

Comment: As said, use a GridViewRowPresenter instead. Take a look at [ListView Styles and Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/listview-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)